# can we add view more option in hero card for long messages

Tags: botframework, bots, chatbot, azure-bot-service

I am using Microsoft bot framework, is it possible to give option as **view more**  for long messages in hero card.

my card is rendering and i am able to see the complete text. since text is very long chat bubble is not fitting in the window. i know we can split the text and send two times but my client is very specific about view more option.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Sanjeev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the channels you are connected to. For **example**, on **Facebook Messenger** this is not feasible as the UI components allowed there do not have this option.

But for other channels that support [Adaptive Cards](https://adaptivecards.io/designer) like these [Partners](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/resources/partners) you might find other solutions like having **dynamic Height** for cards that will support having large texts and many other stuff.

**UPDATE**

I hope this helps as there isn't a "view more" option yet in Adaptive Cards, but there is a Toggle Option like below

[image]

Go to the [Adaptive cards designer](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/) and paste the following (replacing original json) in the **Card Payload Editor** on the bottom left 
After that click on **Preview Mode** on the top right and then click on the preview card, you will have a **TOGGLE Action**

```
{
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"version": "1.0",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "Container",
        "selectAction": {
            "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
            "targetElements": [
                "leg1Details"
            ]
        },
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "ColumnSet",
                "columns": [
                    {
                        "width": "24px",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "type": "Image",
                                "style": "Person",
                                "backgroundColor": "#0078D7",
                                "url": "http://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/assets/smallairplane_white.png"
                            }
                        ],
                        "type": "Column"
                    },
                    {
                        "width": "stretch",
                        "spacing": "Small",
                        "verticalContentAlignment": "Center",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                "text": "**Depart:** Delta Air Lines flight 8471 to Paris"
                            }
                        ],
                        "type": "Column"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "ColumnSet",
                "spacing": "None",
                "columns": [
                    {
                        "width": "24px",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "type": "Image",
                                "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                                "width": "1px",
                                "url": "http://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/assets/palebluedot1x1.png",
                                "height": "20px"
                            }
                        ],
                        "type": "Column"
                    },
                    {
                        "width": "stretch",
                        "spacing": "Small",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                "text": "Bengaluru, Sun 11/12/2017 1:55 AM, 10 hours 41 minutes",
                                "isSubtle": true
                            }
                        ],
                        "type": "Column"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "ColumnSet",
        "id": "leg1Details",
        "isVisible": false,
        "spacing": "None",
        "columns": [
            {
                "width": "24px",
                "padding": "none",
                "backgroundImage": {
                    "url": "http://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/assets/palebluedot1x1.png",
                    "mode": "repeatVertically",
                    "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
                },
                "type": "Column"
            },
            {
                "width": "stretch",
                "spacing": "Small",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "Container",
                        "padding": {
                            "top": "default"
                        },
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "type": "ColumnSet",
                                "columns": [
                                    {
                                        "width": 45,
                                        "items": [
                                            {
                                                "type": "Container",
                                                "padding": "none",
                                                "backgroundImage": "http://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/assets/TxP_Background.png",
                                                "items": [
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "Image",
                                                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                                                        "url": "http://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/assets/TxP_Flight.png"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "type": "Container",
                                                "style": "emphasis",
                                                "spacing": "None",
                                                "items": [
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                                        "text": "Flight to Paris",
                                                        "wrap": true,
                                                        "size": "ExtraLarge",
                                                        "weight": "Lighter",
                                                        "color": "Accent"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                                        "text": "Delta Air Lines flight 8471",
                                                        "wrap": true,
                                                        "size": "Medium",
                                                        "spacing": "Small"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                                        "wrap": true,
                                                        "text": "Confirmation code: ABCDEF",
                                                        "size": "Medium",
                                                        "spacing": "None"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                                        "wrap": true,
                                                        "text": "10 hours 45 minutes",
                                                        "size": "Medium",
                                                        "spacing": "None"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "type": "Column"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "width": 55,
                                        "spacing": "None",
                                        "padding": "default",
                                        "items": [
                                            {
                                                "type": "Container",
                                                "height": "stretch",
                                                "items": [
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "ColumnSet",
                                                        "columns": [
                                                            {
                                                                "width": "auto",
                                                                "items": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                                                        "text": "BLR",
                                                                        "weight": "Lighter",
                                                                        "size": "ExtraLarge"
                                                                    }
                                                                ],
                                                                "type": "Column"
                                                            },
                                                            {
                                                                "width": "stretch",
                                                                "verticalContentAlignment": "Center",
                                                                "items": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "type": "Image",
                                                                        "width": "10000px",
                                                                        "url": "http://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/assets/graydot2x2.png",
                                                                        "height": "2px"
                                                                    }
                                                                ],
                                                                "type": "Column"
                                                            },
                                                            {
                                                                "width": "auto",
                                                                "spacing": "Small",
                                                                "verticalContentAlignment": "Center",
                                                                "items": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "type": "Image",
                                                                        "url": "http://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/assets/smallairplane.png",
                                                                        "height": "16px"
                                                                    }
                                                                ],
                                                                "type": "Column"
                                                            },
                                                            {
                                                                "width": "auto",
                                                                "items": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                                                        "text": "CDG",
                                                                        "weight": "Lighter",
                                                                        "horizontalAlignment": "Right",
                                                                        "size": "ExtraLarge"
                                                                    }
                                                                ],
                                                                "type": "Column"
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "ColumnSet",
                                                        "columns": [
                                                            {
                                                                "width": 1,
                                                                "items": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                                                        "text": "1:55 AM",
                                                                        "size": "Medium"
                                                                    }
                                                                ],
                                                                "type": "Column"
                                                            },
                                                            {
                                                                "width": 1,
                                                                "items": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                                                        "text": "8:10 AM",
                                                                        "horizontalAlignment": "Right",
                                                                        "size": "Medium"
                                                                    }
                                                                ],
                                                                "type": "Column"
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "ColumnSet",
                                                        "spacing": "None",
                                                        "columns": [
                                                            {
                                                                "width": 1,
                                                                "items": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                                                        "isSubtle": true,
                                                                        "wrap": true,
                                                                        "text": "November 12, 2017"
                                                                    }
                                                                ],
                                                                "type": "Column"
                                                            },
                                                            {
                                                                "width": 1,
                                                                "items": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                                                        "isSubtle": true,
                                                                        "wrap": true,
                                                                        "text": "November 12, 2017",
                                                                        "horizontalAlignment": "Right"
                                                                    }
                                                                ],
                                                                "type": "Column"
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "ColumnSet",
                                                        "spacing": "None",
                                                        "columns": [
                                                            {
                                                                "width": 1,
                                                                "items": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                                                        "isSubtle": true,
                                                                        "text": "Bengaluru"
                                                                    }
                                                                ],
                                                                "type": "Column"
                                                            },
                                                            {
                                                                "width": 1,
                                                                "items": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                                                        "isSubtle": true,
                                                                        "text": "Paris",
                                                                        "horizontalAlignment": "Right"
                                                                    }
                                                                ],
                                                                "type": "Column"
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "type": "ColumnSet",
                                                "horizontalAlignment": "Right",
                                                "separator": true,
                                                "spacing": "Large",
                                                "columns": [
                                                    {
                                                        "width": "auto",
                                                        "selectAction": {
                                                            "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                                                            "url": "http://www.microsoft.com"
                                                        },
                                                        "items": [
                                                            {
                                                                "type": "ColumnSet",
                                                                "columns": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "width": "auto",
                                                                        "verticalContentyAlignment": "center",
                                                                        "items": [
                                                                            {
                                                                                "type": "Image",
                                                                                "url": "http://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/assets/smallairplane.png",
                                                                                "height": "16px"
                                                                            }
                                                                        ],
                                                                        "type": "Column"
                                                                    },
                                                                    {
                                                                        "width": "auto",
                                                                        "spacing": "Small",
                                                                        "items": [
                                                                            {
                                                                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                                                                "text": "Check in"
                                                                            }
                                                                        ],
                                                                        "type": "Column"
                                                                    }
                                                                ]
                                                            }
                                                        ],
                                                        "type": "Column"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "width": "auto",
                                                        "spacing": "Large",
                                                        "selectAction": {
                                                            "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                                                            "url": "http://www.microsoft.com"
                                                        },
                                                        "items": [
                                                            {
                                                                "type": "ColumnSet",
                                                                "columns": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "width": "auto",
                                                                        "verticalContentyAlignment": "center",
                                                                        "items": [
                                                                            {
                                                                                "type": "Image",
                                                                                "url": "http://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/assets/calendaricon.png",
                                                                                "height": "16px"
                                                                            }
                                                                        ],
                                                                        "type": "Column"
                                                                    },
                                                                    {
                                                                        "width": "auto",
                                                                        "spacing": "Small",
                                                                        "items": [
                                                                            {
                                                                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                                                                "text": "View in Calendar"
                                                                            }
                                                                        ],
                                                                        "type": "Column"
                                                                    }
                                                                ]
                                                            }
                                                        ],
                                                        "type": "Column"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "type": "Column"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "type": "Column"
            }
        ]
    }
 ]}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response. I need to host my bot in web page.

Comment: You will then be using the Direct Line channel which supports Adaptive Cards. So you I advise you to check them out and use their awesome features! You can create your own custom cards as well.

Comment: i could not find for view more. may be ihave explore more. can you help me with this . like some code or something

Comment: I tried working on ur suggestion, it did work fine in Adaptive card designer. It did not work when i tried to implement in my bot. when i add Action.ToggleVisibility buttons are not rendering. but when i change type to Action.ShowCard or openurl buttons are loading. thanks

Comment: Great im glad it Worked! if my answer was helpful it would be great if you can accept or upvote it! And it would be nice if you can update your answer showcasing how you managed to get it to work, this way others will benefit as well